# Signing the packets with the application name

Tags: java, linux, sockets

When a linux application opens a socket to transfer packets I would like to intercept the socket call and insert the application name into these packets. I'm fairly acquainted with core networking principles; I just have no clue where to start if I want to write a software that can perform such task. Could anyone give me some pointers?

**Updated question**

**The original problem is that:** I want to distinguish each packet based on the the application that generated them, so I can classify them and feed them to my machine learning algorithm.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where Y is your solution that you want to sign packets while X is the unknown problem you want to solve this way. I recommend that you describe the original problem (X) first because maybe there is a better solution to this, like using TLS together with mutual authentication or application level signatures instead of packet signatures.

Comment: Thank you Steffen, I have added the original problem ( I hope that I have understood you currently)

Comment: I don't think that Y is really possible given that there is no such thing as signed packets in the first place (outside from IPSec or similar). But, given the original problem it might be an approach to inspect which application is using which sockets (see `netstat -npt`) and this way associate application with captured packets. Or you can have iptables rules which match by owner etc and tag packets associated with a specific user so they can be used for specific  processing. Or you could socksify the application and thus capture the traffic at an application specific  socks server.

Comment: Steffen would expand on the netstat and iptable approaches; Because I am trying to create a client server application that automate this task. The server tells the client that the packets of which applications to be tagged. So I would like to understand how I can use these approaches.

Comment: with iptables you can have rules applying to packets relating to the socket of a specific user on the system. See documentation for `--uid-owner` and similar in iptables-extensions. With netstat  option `-p` you can find out which process a socket belongs too. More details are out of the scope of the question.